# Extremal points of $L^\infty$ unit ball

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider a compact set $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^N$, and $L^p=L^p(K)$. Let $B_p$ the unit ball in $L^p$, denote by $c$ the convex hull and by $e$ the set of extremal points of a set.

> Can we write $\overline{c(e(B_\infty))}=B_\infty$?

I think yes: $B_\infty$ is (isometric isomorphic to) the unit ball of the dual of $L^1$, and thanks to the compactness of $K$ this space is separable. Thus we can apply the Krein-Milman theorem to get that $\overline{c(e(B_{{L^1}^*}))}^{w^*}=B_{{L^1}^*}$.

But what about $e(B_{{L^1}^*})$? I would appreciate any hint on how to go on from here.

Comment: Krein-Milman applies to any locally convex vector space directly, which $L^\infty$ is. Also, $L^\infty(K)$ is not separable unless $K$ is zero measure.

Comment: In order that $B_\infty$ is weak-star compact, separability is not needed (Banach-Alaoglu). For weak-star *sequential* compactness, separability of $L^1(K)$ is needed, but this is true for any $K\subset \mathbb R^n$, compactness is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The extreme points of $B_\infty$ are functions $u\in L^\infty(K)$ such that $|u(x)|=1$ for almost all $x$.

It is straightforward to check that such functions are extreme points, since $u(x)$ is an extreme point of  $[-1,+1]$ for almost all $x$.

Let $u\in B_\infty$. Denote by $\chi_{\{u>0\}}$ the characteristic function of the set $\{x: \ u(x)>0\}$. Then
$$
u = \chi_{\{u>0\}} \left( \frac12(+1) + \frac12(2u-1)\right) 
+ \chi_{\{u\le0\}} \left( \frac12(-1) + \frac12(2u+1)\right)\\
= \frac12\left( \chi_{\{u>0\}} -\chi_{\{u\le0\}} \right) 
+ \frac12\left( \chi_{\{u>0\}}(2u-1)+\chi_{\{u\le0\}}(2u+1) \right),
$$
which writes $u$ as a convex combination of two elements of $B_\infty$. Then $u$ is an extreme point only if $u=\chi_{\{u>0\}} -\chi_{\{u\le0\}}$, which is equivalent to $|u(x)|=1$ for almost all $x$.

With a similar proof one can prove the claim also for complex-valued functions.